LNK4006 errors when using templates
I have two files, A.cpp and B.cpp, that both include a header file (C.h) which contains a templated class "tempC" and its implementation.
A.cpp compiles fine but B.cpp throws a LNK4006 warning
"public: __cdecl tempC ... already defined in in A.obj; second definition ignored".
I have tried splitting the implementation of the templated class from the header, i.e. put in a file C.cpp, and whilst that works, when i then try to use the compiled lib in a separate project, it throws an "unresolved external " error for the templated functions.
Any help very welcome!
The code is quite large, so not sure how to expose it here, but I've written some pseudo code below which has the key features of the original.
1) snippet from C.h:
#pragma once

template<typename T>
class tempC
{
public:
    tempC();

    void func(std::vector<double>& z);
};


template<typename T>
tempC<T>::tempC() {}

template<typename T>
tempC<T>::tempC(std::vector<double> t) : m_t(t) { // default behaviour}

template<>
tempC<MT>::tempC(std::vector<double> t) : m_t(t) { // do something else }

template<>
tempC<MTBB>::tempC(std::vector<double> t) : m_t(t) {// do something different }

template<>
void tempC<MT>::func(std::vector<double>& z) { // specialisation of member function}

etc


2) snippet from A.cpp
#include <C.h>

double value()
{
    // key part
    size_t N = 100;
    std::vector<double> T(N, 0.0);
    tempC<SOBOLBB> gen(T);
}


3) snippet from B.cpp is exactly the same as in 2, i.e.
#include <C.h>

double value()
{
    // key part
    size_t N = 100;
    std::vector<double> T(N, 0.0);
    tempC<SOBOLBB> gen(T);
}

I have tried splitting the implementation of the templated class from the header, i.e. put in a file C.cpp, and whilst that works, when i then try to use the compiled lib in a separate project, it throws an "unresolved external " error for the templated functions.
I have also tried replacing the
#pragma once 

by
#ifndef __tempC_h
#define __tempC_h

#endif

but that doesn't help.

The #pragma directive should be in the header file not the .cpp files. However that will not make any difference to the issue. Can you provide the complete error message that you see to make it clear which statement is the problem?

Thanks, yes, a typo on my part when writing the pseudo code.

@OldBoy, here are the errors:

1>B.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: __cdecl tempC::tempC(class std::vector<double,class std::allocator >)" (??0?$tempC@VMT@@@@QEAA@V?$vector@NV?$allocator@N@std@@@std@@@Z) already defined in A.obj; second definition ignored

1>B.obj : warning LNK4006: "public: void __cdecl tempC::func(class std::vector<double,class std::allocator > &)" (?func@?$tempC@VMT@@@@QEAAXAEAV?$vector@NV?$allocator@N@std@@@std@@@Z) already defined in A.obj; second definition ignored

As far as I can see the issue is the tempC<MT>::tempC(std::vector<double> t) implementation being inside the header file. That means that when you compile A and B they both create a public function with the same name. Which is fine if you only want to run A or B in isolation. But when you link them together they both have a definition of a function with the same name, which confuses the linker. I'm afraid I am not expert in the use of templates but I think you will need to rework yours to keep just the declarations in the header, and all implementations in one only of the .cpp files.
